# Does the image of a bounded sequence in a NLS under a compact operator have a convergent subsequence or merely a Cauchy subsequence?

Tags: banach-spaces, compact-operators

Wikpedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) that if $X,Y$ are normed spaces and $T: X \to Y$ is a linear operator, then the following two statements are equivalent:

> - $T$ is a compact operator
> - for any bounded sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $X$, the sequence $(T x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains a converging subsequence.

To give a counter example, the identity map on $\mathbb{Q}$ is compact. But there are bounded sequences of rational numbers with Cauchy subsequences but not convergent subsequences.

If $Y$ is complete, and therefore a Banach space, then all Cauchy sequences converge. But Wikipedia clearly says this is for an NLS, not necessarily a complete NLS (Banach).

Is my counter-example wrong or is Wikipedia wrong?

Comment: I think this pretty much shows that the identity map on $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact. For the unit ball to be relatively compact, you'd need a sequence that would converge to an irrational in $[-1,1]$ to have a convergent subsequence in $\mathbb{Q}$, which indeed is not possible.

Comment: In my textbook, if $X,Y$ are NLS and $T: X \to Y$ is linear, then if $X$ is finite dimensional then $T$ is compact.

Comment: I'm not sure if $\mathbb{Q}$ counts as a NLS, because we require it to use either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as a field of scalars. But any identity map on finite dimensional NLS is compact. And if that space is not complete, Cauchy sequences don't necessarily converge.

Comment: For that theorem to work, you pretty much need to have $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as your field of scalars, as shown by this example. (The [French page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_de_Riesz#Contre-exemples_sur_d'autres_corps) for Riesz's lemma has some examples of that kind of counterexamples for other fields that do not figure on the English page)

Comment: Another example tied to $\mathbb{Q}$ is that $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space but its unit ball is relatively compact (this figures in the French page I linked), whereas with the field of scalars $\mathbb{R}$ infinite-dimensional unit balls are never relatively compact.

Comment: OK, forget $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there any single dimensional incomplete vector space? I can't easily think of an example. But the identity map in such a space would be compact and the image of any bounded sequence would have a subsequence that is Cauchy but not necessarily convergent. Does that work?

Comment: All finite-dimensional vector spaces *over $\mathbb{R}$* are complete, and $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1$-dimensional but its identity map is not a compact operator.